# FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified while running fastapi project using manage-fastapi

Tags: python, fastapi

I am getting the following error when I try to run my fastapi project

```
1491, in _execute_child     
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I am using manage-fastapi as package manager for creating fastapi project
find the link for manage-fastapi https://github.com/ycd/manage-fastapi

I am getting this error when I am executing `fastapi run`

Comment: Do you have `uvicorn` installed?

Comment: installing uvicorn solved the issue, Thank you Abdul.

Answer (score 2):

From the traceback it seems like `manage-fastapi` is trying to execute some external commands. The way to execute external commands in python is using `subprocess` module. So [searching over the `manage-fastapi` repository finds only two instances of `subprocess` call](https://github.com/ycd/manage-fastapi/search?q=subprocess). One is,

```
def validate_project(cls, values: dict):
        try:
            values["username"] = subprocess.check_output(
                ["git", "config", "--get", "user.name"]
            )
            values["email"] = subprocess.check_output(
                ["git", "config", "--get", "user.email"]
            )
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
            ...
```

And the other is

```
subprocess.call(["uvicorn", f"{app_file}:app", *args])
```

The former have an `except` clause, so even if `subprocess.check_output` raises an exception the `except` clause will silently bypass it. But the other one does not have any exception mechanism.

So I strongly believe that `uvicorn` dependency missing in your project, and [installing this](https://github.com/encode/uvicorn#quickstart) will most likely resolve the issue.